# Oracle SQL Group By, use value from latest date

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Basically, I'm looking to count the matching "group by" records where the most current value in a field, for that group, is equal to a requested value.

So, for example, let's say that I have:

```
A, B, 2, 1/1/2015
E, F, 9, 12/1/2014
A, B, 6, 1/15/2015
E, F, 4, 1/8/2015
A, B, 4, 1/10/2015
C, D, 4, 2/4/2015
A, B, 4, 2/1/2015
C, D, 22, 2/16/2015
```

and I'm looking for the count of "Field1/2 grouped" records where the most current value of field 3, of that group, is a "4". I would like the results to be:

```
4: for group "A, B"
2: for group "E, F"
```

Group "C, D" would not show up in my results at all.

Hopefully, this makes a little sense.

My exact problem is slightly more complex than this...but, I think this will get me over a large hurdle.

Comment: Sorry, I could not make sense of it...

Comment: What you mean with: `where the most current value of field 3,` ?

Comment: Sorry, I'll try better: For example, I want to get 4 for group "A, B" because "4" was the value on the latest date of group "A, B". So, not the max value in field3, but the value in field3, on the max date of field4, is "4"...for that group. And, once it's known that "A, B" is a match...add up all the "A, B".

Comment: You need to define 'latest' .  Clearly it's not determined by the date value, as the latest date for group "E,F" has a value of `9` .

Comment: Okay, you've fixed your data

Comment: Yes, sorry about that type-o.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sub-query factoring clause includes two analytic functions, one to count the number of rows per group and the other identifies the latest record.  These are used as filters in the outer query.  The pipes are Oracle's concatenation operator, and format the output as you requested.

```
with cte as ( select t23.*
                     , count(*) over (partition by grp1, grp2) as grp_cnt
                     , row_number() over (partition by grp1, grp2 order by ts desc) as latest
              from t23 )
select  
       grp_cnt || 
       ': for group "' ||
       grp1 || ',' || grp2 ||
       '"'
from cte
where latest = 1
and val = 4
/
```

[Working SQL Fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2915d/7)

Analytic functions are highly neat, because they allow us to do some really powerful stuff in pure SQL.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174)

Comment: This is more advanced than I'm used to, but it looks promising and something cool to learn!

Comment: Yeah, you should definitely learn more about analytic functions.

Comment: If you use `row_number()` instead of `rank()`, you can omit the `distinct` clause.

Comment: You do need `distinct` if you use `rank()`, though, as otherwise, you'll get duplicates if there is more than one row with the same (most recent) time stamp and `val = 4`.

Comment: Does the analytics function approach always trigger a full table scan for this case? I played around with indexes on the relevant fields in SQL Fiddle, but was unable to make the query optimizer use any of them.

Comment: @markusk - performance tuning is a complex matter.  Yes this does a full table scan, but one FTS may be the more efficient compared to three index range scans..  It depends on data volumes and skew.   Even if indexes could offer a more efficient access path for this query, the overhead of maintaining them might be wasted if the query is run infrequently.

Comment: This worked like a charm! I added my other items to this task, and it all fell right into place! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
with selected as (
    select field1, field2
    from some_table
     where field3 = 4
      and (field1, field2, field4) in (
        select field1, field2, max(field4)
        from some_table
        group by field1, field2
    )
)
select field1, field2, count(*)
from some_table join selected using(field1, field2)
group by field1, field2
```

With indexes on `(field1, field2, field4)` and on `field3`, this executes efficiently according to SQL Fiddle.

[APC's solution with windowing functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29022270/108326) is shorter and more elegant, I'm including this alternative for completeness. This solution may also be more efficient if there's a large number of rows, as it avoids any table scans when the suggested indexes are in place.

Comment: I think this will not get the results he want... it will not get the `4: for group "A, B",` since the max for this group on field3  is 6

Comment: I want to get 4 for group "A, B" because "4" was the value on the latest date of group "A, B". So, not the max value in field3, but the value in field3 on the max date of field4 is "4".

Comment: And, once it's known that "A, B" is a match...add up all the "A, B"

Comment: One more clarification...if the latest value for a group in field3 is a "4", I want to count every row that has "A, B"...regardless of the field3 value. The "latest value" is an indicator of "Count all rows for this group"

Comment: Updated to match latest clarification. (Once more, untested, but hopefully useful to figure out the proper solution.)

Comment: In the inner select, is the first part, in the "and" supposed to be "st.field2"?